# Point sub domain to folder in root directory

Tags: .htaccess, directory, point

I have registered a domain with Godaddy, e.g. www.domain.com

In my domain management I have the domain pointing to "/"

And I have a sub domain pointing to "/"

I have set up a .htaccess in my root directory.

Here is the .htaccess code I am using...

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder_1/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /subfolder_1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  mysub_2.domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder_2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /subfolder_2/$1 [L]
```

---

The top rewrite works fine, I can go to domain.com or www.domain.com and it will point to subfolder_1.

But if I visit mysub_2.domain.com I can't seem to point it to the folder subfolder_2.

The folder structure is as such:

Root
  - subfolder_1
  - subfolder_2
  - stats
  - cgi

Any ideas? Been working on this for a few hours and failing.

Thank you,
James

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  domain.com$ [NC]
```

also matches the host `mysub_2.domain.com`. You should change the 2 host check conditions to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^mysub_2.domain.com$ [NC]
```